# import random.randint guess game

Tags: python

- problem1 = else not working when i type for example some character it crash
- problem2 = when i win(guess number) it wont do anything (it should print (more in code))

```
import random

print("guess number 1,5")
player = int(input("type guess: "))
pc = random.randint(1, 5)
attemp = 1


while player != pc:
    attemp = +1
    if player != pc:
        print("your guess", int(player), "pc", int(pc))
        player = int(input("type guess: "))
        pc = random.randint(1, 5)

    elif player == pc:
        print(
            "you win with number",
            int(player),
            "you had",
            int(attemp),
            "attempts",
        )
    else:
        print("please type int num only")
        hráč = int(input("type type: "))
        pc = random.randint(1, 5)
```

Comment: When will else get executed?

Comment: You're not catching the exception that `int()` throws when it can't convert a string to integer. An `else:` won't do that (why would it?).

Comment: `attemp = +1` should be `attemp += 1`.

Comment: If the input contain characters other than numerals, it will crash at `player = int(input("type guess: "))`. May be you should catch it and in the exception handling part you could add else message

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different places where the code doesn't work as intended.

1. `int(input("type guess: "))` will crash if you type in something that is not an integer, because `int(...)` tries to convert it to an integer and fails. The easiest way to fix this is to catch the exception and ask again for a number in a loop:

```py
while True:
    try:
        player = int(input("type guess: ")) # If this line fails, break won't be executed
        break # If the conversion went well we exit the loop
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid number')
```

2. `while player != pc` will exit the loop as soon as the user inputs the right number, and the code that prints the success message will not be executed. To fix this, change the loop in a `while True` and insert a `break` after you print the success message:

```py
while True:
    [...]
    elif player == pc:
        print("you win with number", [...])
        break
```

3. You may also notice that the if...elif branches inside the loop cover every possible condition, so the final `else` part will never be executed. This is not a problem, since we are already handling the input error part when reading the number, so we can remove the else part completely. To simplify the code even more, the condition in the elif isn't necessary, since it's the opposite of the condition in the if, so the logic can be reduced to this:

```py
<read number from user>

while True:
    if player != pc:
        <print failure message, get new number from the user and new random number>

    else:
        <print success message>
        break
```

Finally, there is a small mistake in your code:

`attemp = +1` probably doesn't do what you want it to do, in that it sets `attemp` to be equal to +1. I'm assuming you meant `attemp += 1`, which increments the value by 1

---

The final code becomes:

```py
import random

print("guess number 1,5")
while True:
    try:
        player = int(input("type guess: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid number')
pc = random.randint(1, 5)
attemp = 1


while True:
    attemp += 1
    if player != pc:
        print("your guess", int(player), "pc", int(pc))
        while True:
            try:
                player = int(input("type guess: "))
                break
            except ValueError:
                print('Invalid number')
        pc = random.randint(1, 5)

    else:
        print(
            "you win with number",
            int(player),
            "you had",
            int(attemp),
            "attempts",
        )
        break
```

This is not the cleanest possile way to do it (for example, reading a number from the user is a perfect candidate for a separate function, or you could restructure the logic so that in each iteration of the `while True` loop you first ask for a number, check it against the random number, print the right message and break if necessary), but I don't want to modify the code too much